# Node error handler bugs when using error pattern (err, req, res, next)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, error-handling

I am currently running node with the express middleware and handling request with the GET method. Errors like 404s or 500s are handled at the end of my script, after the GET method, but so far I have not been able to use Node's standard error handling method with err,req,res,next. The below code works fine for me. But ...

server.js

```
...

// Routing

app.use('/', function (req, res, next) {
    req.const = {
        nonce: nonce,
        publicRoot: publicRoot,
        client: client,
        cachelifespan: cachelifespan
    };
    next();
}, router);


// Error handling

app.use('/', function (req, res, next) {
    req.const = {
        nonce: nonce,
        publicRoot: publicRoot,
    };
    next();
}, errorHandler);

...
```

errorhandler.js:

```
...

errorHandler.use(function (req, res) {
    let id = req.ip;
    let url = req.url;

    // Import 

    let nonce = req.const.nonce;
    let publicRoot = req.const.publicRoot;

    res.statusCode = 500;
    let status = res.statusCode;

    try {
        let localPath = path.join(publicRoot, req.path);
        fs.accessSync(localPath);
    } catch (err) {
        status = 404;
    };

    if (req.accepts('html')) {
        try {
            res.render('system/error', { title: status.toString(), description: 'This is an error!', nonce: 'nonceValue' }, function(err, html) {
                html = html.replace("nonceValue", nonce);
                res.send(html);
            });
        } catch (err) {
            logError(id, status, req.url, err)
        };
    } else if (req.accepts('json')) {
        res.send({ error: status.toString() });
    } else {
        res.type('txt').send("error: " + status.toString());
    }

    logError(id, status, req.url);
});

...
```

... if I try to write the app.use function to ...

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
```

... it bugs and Node's default error handler takes over.
I am not entirely sure how to fix that.
Or if I am doing the error handling right?

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is `errorHandler`?

Comment: errorHandler is the stuff inside errorhandler.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem.

Inside server.js (the main app js), I load the errorHandler in the beginning of the file:

```
const errorHandler = require('./errorhandler');
```

And in the last step, after the basic routing, I added the errorhandler:

```
// Routing

app.use('/', function (req, res, next) {
    req.const = {
        nonce: nonce,
        publicRoot: publicRoot,
        client: client,
        cachelifespan: cachelifespan
    };
    next();
}, router);


// Error handling

app.use('/', function (req, res, next) {
    req.const = {
        nonce: nonce,
        publicRoot: publicRoot,
    };
    next();
}, errorHandler);
```

Inside the separate errorhandler file:

```
//--------------------
// NODE
//--------------------

const express = require('express');
const errorHandler = express.Router();

//--------------------
// LOGGING
//--------------------

const { getDate, logOutput, logError } = require('./logger');

//--------------------
// ROUTER
//--------------------

errorHandler.use(function (req, res) {
    let id = req.ip;
    let url = req.url;

    // Import 

    let nonce = req.const.nonce;
    let publicRoot = req.const.publicRoot;

    // Cookies 

    let insultor = "Samuel L Jackson says";
    let insults = ['Motherfucker!!!', 'Son_of_a_bitch!!!', 'Asshole!!!', 'Punkass_motherfucker!!!', 'Whiny_little_bitch!!!', 'You_deserve_to_die_and_I_hope_you_burn_in_hell!!!', 'Web_motherfucker_do_you_speak_it?'];
    let number = Math.floor(Math.random() * insults.length);
    let insulted = false;

    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(req.cookies)) {
        if (key.toString() == insultor) {
            value = value.toString() + "_-_" + insults[number];
            res.cookie(insultor, value);
            insulted = true;
        }
    }

    if (!insulted) {
        res.cookie(insultor, insults[number]);
    }

    res.statusCode = 500;
    let status = res.statusCode;

    try {
        let localPath = path.join(publicRoot, req.path);
        fs.accessSync(localPath);
    } catch (err) {
        status = 404;
    };

    if (req.accepts('html')) {
        try {
            res.render('system/error', { title: status.toString(), description: 'This is an error, Motherfucker!', nonce: 'nonceValue' }, function(err, html) {
                html = html.replace("nonceValue", nonce);
                res.send(html);
            });
        } catch (err) {
            logError(id, status, req.url, err)
        };
    } else if (req.accepts('json')) {
        res.send({ error: status.toString() });
    } else {
        res.type('txt').send("error: " + status.toString());
    }

    logError(id, status, req.url);
});

module.exports = errorHandler;
```